# How to use same drive to access files from Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

Can I use the same internal hard drive to save my files from Ubuntu and Windows? I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10, and the data drive I wish to share is D: in Windows.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Drive D" in Ubuntu. But you can use one disk or a partition in both OS.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, so long as you understand the differences.

Linux (and therefore Ubuntu) don't use drive letters. Instead, they name drives, and name partitions and volumes of storage made from drives.

When you run `sudo gparted -l` in a Ubuntu terminal window, you will see each drive and how it is subdivided for storage for Windows, Linux, and other OS.

Ubuntu can access files and folders on a Windows [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) drive like D: and it will appear under its Linux name in the Ubuntu file manager, [GNOME Files](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Files) AKA [Nautilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files). Just use it when you need it.

It doesn't work the other way; you can't automagically access files on an Ubuntu [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) formatted drive from Windows, or other Linux formatted drives using other types of drive partitions. There are drivers which can be added to Windows to enable that, but every time I have tried them, the Ubuntu drive gets corrupted and I lose date.